# When setting variable to object, set it to all nested objects within

Tags: python, oop, attributes, decorator, python-decorators

I have the following code that works:

```
class fundamental_object():

    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x

class encapsulator_object():

    def __init__(self,x,obj_list):
        self._x = x
        self.obj_list = obj_list

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.x

    @x.setter
    def x(self,new_x):
        print('in setter!')
        self._x = new_x
        for obj in self.obj_list:
            obj.x = new_x

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    x = 10
    obj_1 = fundamental_object(x)
    obj_2 = fundamental_object(x)
    obj_list = [obj_1,obj_2]
    encapsulator = encapsulator_object(x,obj_list)

    encapsulator.x = 20
    print(encapsulator._x)
    print(obj_1.x) # all of these are also updated to 20.
```

As you can see, the idea is that, whenever I change the attribute "x" of the encapsulator object, I want all nested objects inside it (fundamental_objects) to also be updated with this new variable "x". However, from a user standpoint, this gets confusing really quickly, since, if I understand correctly, "x" is an integer for "fundamental_object", whereas "x" is a method for "encapsulator_object", and to actually access the integer in the encapsulator I would need to use "_x". Is there any easy/correct/pythonic way to make it so the following works :

```
    x = 10
    obj_1 = fundamental_object(x)
    obj_2 = fundamental_object(x)
    obj_list = [obj_1,obj_2]
    encapsulator = encapsulator_object(x,obj_list)

    encapsulator.x = 20
    print(encapsulator.x) # notice the underscore is now gone!  
    print(obj_1.x)        # this would be updated to 20 as well
```

I understand that it is possible to make it so "fundamental_objects" also have "_x" as the integer variable, which would somewhat reduce the confusion, but still, I'd like to completely get rid of the underscores if possible! (right now I get an infinite recursion). Thanks!

Comment: Your `encapsulator_object.x` property is *infinitely recursive*. You meant `return self._x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code. I only changed your getter method in your property. Now it is pointing to the `self._x`.

```
class fundamental_object():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x


class encapsulator_object():
    def __init__(self, x, obj_list):
        self._x = x
        self.obj_list = obj_list

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x   # -----> here

    @x.setter
    def x(self, new_x):
        print('in setter!')
        self._x = new_x
        for obj in self.obj_list:
            obj.x = new_x


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = 10
    obj_1 = fundamental_object(x)
    obj_2 = fundamental_object(x)
    obj_list = [obj_1, obj_2]
    encapsulator = encapsulator_object(x, obj_list)

    encapsulator.x = 20
    print(encapsulator.x)  # notice the underscore is now gone!
    print(obj_1.x)  # this would be updated to 20 as well
```

As an alternative you can completely remove `x` or `_x` in `encapsulator_object`. Then in your getter you can find `x` within the `self.obj_list` :

```
class fundamental_object():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x


class encapsulator_object():
    def __init__(self, obj_list):
        self.obj_list = obj_list

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.obj_list[0].x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, new_x):
        print('in setter!')
        for obj in self.obj_list:
            obj.x = new_x
```

Bear in mind that, in this example because we decided to pick first item in the list, all objects must have the same `x` value. There is no need to worry about it after you can the setter though. I mentioned it if you want to call the getter before setter.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Indeed, the first one works and so I've accepted it as an answer. However, there's still part of me that finds it difficult to convince a user that the underscore is needed at all (if they decide to enter the code). What is its purpose? It would be only an intermediate variable that allows for the setter method to do what I want?

Comment: @Zepphit Second part also works, just remove the `x` from `encapsulator = encapsulator_object(x, obj_list)` because it isn't needed anymore. We eliminated `x`.  If you ensure that all the objects you pass into the list have the same `x` property, then go with the second one. If not, make sure you call the `setter` first and again go with the second one. there is no underscore at all

Comment: Thank you but I don't feel comfortable using the second approach due to the self.obj_list[0].x part. I still would like for the encapsulator_object to have its own "variable" per se, and not refer to the variables inside their own objects. The other away around would be better but still not ideal imo...